# UICollectionView effect on iPhone

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm writing an application and I would like to insert the same effect as this photo below. 
I think it was implemented a collection view but I do not understand how to create the effect that is seen by the red arrow.
I think they are three cells one above the other but with a different angle
Can you help? 
Thanks
[UICollectionView Effect](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/2501/dgqa.png)

P.S.: Sorry for link but i don't have sufficient point for insert image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial) achieves that. Look at steps 53-55.

The way he does it there is to have more photos for each section.
You could also do it in a simpler way by just drawing 1-2 UIViews below each cell and rotate them just so that only their edges appear.

It depends on the effect you are after.

Comment: Great !!
I have created two objects of type UIView, where I set the TAG on the storyboard.
After that I then made the rotation with the following property


firstView.transform CGAffineTransformMakeRotation = (-0.0523598776);
secondView.transform CGAffineTransformMakeRotation = (0.0523598776);

Thank you so much ... really very very useful ... because it is very simple

Comment: Simple is (almost) always better! ;)